# HTML - Text/Button Alignment (CSS Media)

Tags: html, css

> https://jsfiddle.net/5d401nso/1/

```
#mobileview{
  /*background-image:url("");
  background-size:100% 100%;*/
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
  #mobileview{

width:411px;
height:411px;
   }
}
@media(max-width: 500px){
    #mobileview{

width:411px;
height:411px;
}
}
```

Above is the jsfiddle that i have created.

> Current Problem: Not Supporting Mobile View and looking a ways to
>   change the text and button alignment from center to "left" when in
>   mobile view

Solution That i wanted: When in mobile view ( max width 768px or 500px ), the text and button will align to left side instead of center.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the quote/code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: @Paulie_D , this is the media query that i have used to make (image) work, but I met some problem with "text/button"

Comment: If a question is closed then **Edit** it to **Fix** it. Don't just copy/paste it unchanged into a new question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put p { text-align: left } inside your @media {} at whatever breakpoint you want it to happen. However small tipp. To make it even more responsive give your image a max-width instead of a static width, so your image will resize whenever your screen does. Also note you have the exact settings for 500 and 700px. If you say @media(max-width: 700px) it will apply to every thing wich is smaller than 700px. You don't need to define 500px if your want 500px down. If you want something to happen within 500px and 700px us (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px)

```
@media(max-width: 500px){
  #mobileview{
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
  }
  p {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```